# how to get logged in user id in jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

how to get logged in user id in jsf 2.0

I am unable to get the user id. I tried the following methods.

xhtml page

```
<h:outputText value="#{request.remoteUser}"></h:outputText>

<h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userId}"></h:outputText>
```

Viewscoped bean class.

```
public String getUserId() {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    System.out.println ("User"+ctx.getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
               userId =ctx.getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    return userId;
}
```

Should i do any initialization in web.xml? or should my bean class extend or implement any other class?

Comment: How are you authenticating users? This code expects that you're doing it by container managed authentication using `<security-constraint>` in `web.xml` and so on. If you're using homegrown authentication using for example a session scoped bean and a filter then checking it through container managed authentication APIs obviously won't work.

Comment: Have you set [constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#bncbk) on the resources?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your inputs. issue got solved.